# Inconsistancy with Firebase Phone Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

My Firebase phone authentication is inconsistent with sending the verification codes. Out of 6 testers, 3 received the Firebase code while 3 of the testers did not receive the code. All 6 testers are using IOS 10.3.2. Firebase does not return an error when the phone number is submitted but the code is still never sent for half of the numbers. There is no error when `verifyPhoneNumber` is called which means the verification code should have been sent. Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey @SmedleyDSlap which country are you experiencing these low delivery rates? It is possible carriers are dropping these messages due to sender ID, message content, etc.

Comment: @bojeil All 6 are in the United States. That may be possible even though one of the testers and I both have T-Mobile and the code was sent on mine but not his. Even more interesting was that if I put my number on his phone the verification code was sent to my phone but he was still not able to receive a code for his own number on his own phone.

Comment: Hey @SmedleyDSlap, you should report this to Firebase support. You may need to provide the test phone number that is not receiving the message.

Comment: @bojeil Alright I will do that thanks

Comment: We have faced the same issue. The problem is that T-Mobile blocks short codes SMS for some users. That user can call T-Mobile can call their support at 611 and ask to get these texts. We have not been able to find a way around this, for now. Would appreciate insights from other folks.